# Sort a List by the column of a different list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

On the select and sorting query below ... how would I be able to do the orderby of tmp on the TagId order of global?

Two lists ... both have different number of items, but both have a field called TagId. I want to return the list of expensesSummary_MemberTmp but sorted by the order of TagId from expensesSummary_MemberTmp.

```
var expensesSummary_Member = from global in expensesSummary_Global.Select(x => x.TagId).ToList()
                             join tmp in expensesSummary_MemberTmp
                             on global equals tmp.TagId
                             orderby tmp.TagId
                             select tmp;
```

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand what's the problem?

Comment: Let's say `expensesSummary_MemberTmp` list has TagIds `{77,11,13,2}`, and `expensesSummary_Global` has `{13,77}`. Should their items be sorted as `{77,13}` because 77 is ahead of 13 on `expensesSummary_MemberTmp`?

Comment: expensesSummary_Global contains the master list e.g. TagIds {77,11,13,2} (this order must remain fixed). Then expensesSummary_MemberTmp would contain the smaller list {13,77}. I need expensesSummary_MemberTmp to return its results as {77,13} because of the order of expensesSummary_Global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the order of the first sequence, you shouldn't order the result at all:

```
var expensesSummary_Member =
    from global in expensesSummary_Global.Select(x => x.TagId).ToList()
    join tmp in expensesSummary_MemberTmp
    on global equals tmp.TagId
    select tmp;
```

Comment: On inverting the join the compiler says:
The name 'global' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked that. But that solution is wrong anyways, as it was based on a wrong assumption.

Comment: This basically what I need from the previous comment I made on my post:
expensesSummary_Global contains the master list e.g. TagIds {77,11,13,2} (this order must remain fixed). Then expensesSummary_MemberTmp would contain the smaller list {13,77}. I need expensesSummary_MemberTmp to return its results as {77,13} because of the order of expensesSummary_Global

Comment: Realising now the sorting of the order was probably the issue and shouldve just left alone